# Spring Batch- Read Footer in fixed length file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

I wanted to validate the number of records in the file be equal to the number mentioned in the footer row.

is there any inbuilt functionality within spring batch to read fixed-width file footer row?

I tried to use the custom fieldset mapper to validate the number of records to be same as mentioned in the footer row.

```
new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<FieldSet>()
                .name("personItemReader")
                .resource(fileName)
                .fixedLength()
                .columns(getRange())
                .names(getNames())
                .fieldSetMapper(new PassThroughFieldSetMapper())
                .linesToSkip(1)
                .build();

public class PersonFileReader implements ItemStreamReader<Person> {

private final ItemStreamReader<FieldSet> itemStreamReader;
private int recordCount = 0;
private int expectedRecordCount = 0;
private StepExecution stepExecution;
private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonFileReader.class);



 public PersonFileReader(@Qualifier("flatFileReader") ItemStreamReader itemStreamReader) {
        this.itemStreamReader = itemStreamReader;
    }

    @Override
    public Person read() throws Exception {
        return process(itemStreamReader.read());
    }

  //code removed

    @AfterStep
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution execution) {
        if (recordCount == expectedRecordCount) {
            return execution.getExitStatus();
        } else {
            return ExitStatus.STOPPED;
        }
    }


    private Person process(FieldSet fieldSet) {
        Person result = null;
        if (fieldSet != null) {
            if (fieldSet.getFieldCount() > 1) {

                logger.info("fieldSet", fieldSet.getFieldCount());

                result = Person.builder()
                        .name(fieldSet.readString(0))
                        .lastName(fieldSet.readString(1))
                        .age(fieldSet.readInt(2))
                        .salary(fieldSet.readDouble(3))
                        .houseNumber(fieldSet.readInt(4))
                        .line1(fieldSet.readString(5))
                        .line2(fieldSet.readString(6)).build();


                recordCount++;
            } else {
                expectedRecordCount = fieldSet.readInt(0);

                if (expectedRecordCount != this.recordCount) {
                    this.stepExecution.setTerminateOnly();
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

But this fails to read the footer with an exception.

```
ogg.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException: Parsing error at line: 6 in resource=[file [D:\Data\Study\spring-batch\batch-process\src\main\resources\static\file1.txt]], input=[4]
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.IncorrectLineLengthException: Line is shorter than max range 66
```

**Sample File.**

```
Name        lastName         age salary HouseNo AddLine1  AddLine2
Andrew         Green          25 26000     10 Avenue      Glasgow 
Ben            Brown          32 28500     11 Avenue      Glasgow 
Celia          Black          29 28000     12 Avenue      Glasgow 
Steve          Pink           41 52000     13 Avenue      Glasgow 
4
```

Comment: Take a look at [SingleItemPeekableItemReader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/SingleItemPeekableItemReader.html), it allows you to peek one item ahead and see if it's the footer record.

Comment: How to differentiate between the footer record and bad record having insufficient length? How to stop the reader from reading till the end?

Comment: It's up to you to implement that logic. The idea is to create a custom reader that uses a `SingleItemPeekableItemReader` to look ahead one item, then do whatever logic you want to apply (check your conditions and return `null` or throw an exception or wrap the item in an entity with additional flags, etc).

Comment: Ok. So the idea is if the peek record is null then the current record is footer. Am I right?

Comment: yes, something like that.